# Return a string value based on the values in the list in Python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

After generating a random list with 0s and 1s

`decision =  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

I want to generate another list which returns 'pass' values in the decision are 1, and 'fail' if values are 0

```
['fail', 'fail', 'pass', 'pass', 'pass', 'fail', 'fail', 'pass',....'fail']
```

I tried list comprehension using,

```
newlist = ["pass" for k in decision if k == 0]
```

but I could not think of a way to integrate else condition if `k==1`.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the condition in the value part of the comprehension"

```
newlist = ["pass" if k == 1 else "fail" for k in decision]
```

Alternatively, in case you have more values create a dictionary:

```
res_dict = {
    0  : "Equal",
    1  : "Higher",
    -1 : "Lower",
}

newlist = [res_dict.get(x) for x in decision]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know my answer is not what you want but I believe it will be easier if you just use `True` or `False`. Here the code:

```
decision = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
result = [d == 1 for d in decision] # // So 1 will be True and 0 will be False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter=0
otherlist=[]
for element in mylist:
    if element == 0:
        otherlist[counter]="fail"
    else:
        otherlist[counter]="pass"
    counter += 1
```

It doesnt use comprehension but it'll do the trick. Hope this helps.
An even faster option would be:

```
otherlist = []
for element in mylist:
    if element == 0:
        otherlist.append("fail")
    else:
        otherlist.append("pass")
```

You can also allow 0s to represent `False` and 1s to represent `True`

```
otherlist = []
for element in mylist:
    if element == 0:
        otherlist.append(False)
    else:
        otherlist.append(True)
```